# Set of minipages appears after blank page

Tags: minipage

I have 4 minipages side by side but they appear after blank page, how it can be avoided?

Secondly there is thin white space between the pages, how to remove that

```
\begin{document}
\noindent
\fcolorbox{red}{red}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.05\textwidth}%%%%a
A
\end{minipage}}
\fcolorbox{green}{green}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.3\textwidth}%%%%a
B
\end{minipage}}
\fcolorbox{blue}{blue}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.05\textwidth}%%%%a
C
\end{minipage}}
\fcolorbox{yellow}{yellow}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.6\textwidth}%%%%a
D
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `\textheight`, are you giving this intentionally? Because, if you remove this then the `blankpage` issue solved, just giving `\ignorespaces` and `%` symbol at end of minipage tag, that will solve the thin white space issue solves, refer the below codes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\null\removelastskip\nointerlineskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.05\textwidth}%%%%a
A
\end{minipage}}\ignorespaces%
\fcolorbox{green}{green}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.3\textwidth}%%%%a
B
\end{minipage}}\ignorespaces%
\fcolorbox{blue}{blue}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.05\textwidth}%%%%a
C
\end{minipage}}\ignorespaces%
\fcolorbox{yellow}{yellow}{% 
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{.6\textwidth}%%%%a
D
\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, I want the minipage height equal to page height. Is it possible here?

Comment: @ZEESHAN Please check the updated answer...